# VS Code works in one WSL but not in other

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

So I have two WSLs (version 2). Kali and Ubuntu. The `code` command works in Kali but Ubuntu says `Command not found`. Since it works in WSL, CMD and PowerShell, it is there in PATH variables. Any help?

edit: Ubuntu doesn't read VS Code in PATH variables, while Kali does. I opened the Environment Variables Wizard. VS Code is there.

Answer (score 0):

In a "normal" case, like you are seeing in your Kali instance, WSL's `init` appends the Windows path to your Linux path.  There are two things that I can think of that would cause that to *not* be happening correctly under your Ubuntu instance:

- You or a script that you ran in Ubuntu modified your shell's startup files (assuming Bash, typically `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`) to edit the PATH, possibly removing the Windows elements, or at least the VSCode element.

  Try running that instance without any Bash startup files (from PowerShell or CMD) with:

  ```
  PS> wsl -d Ubuntu -e bash --noprofile --norc
  ```

  and then try `code .`.  This, of course, assumes that your Ubuntu instance is named `Ubuntu`.  If it's named something else (`wsl -l`) then edit the `-d Ubuntu` as needed.  You might also try launching it as `wsl -d Ubuntu -e sh -c 'code .'`

  If that works, examine your startup files for any modifications to `PATH`.
- Less likely (because you should know if you did this one), is that you can disable the WSL feature that appends the Windows PATH in a particular distribution/instance.  Check for the existence of a `/etc/wsl.conf` file -- If it exists, the line `appendWindowsPath=false` would cause the behavior that you are seeing as well.  Simply change the offending setting to `true`.  Exit your Ubuntu instance, run `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` (again, substituting the correct distro name) and then restart.  Check your `PATH` and try `code .` again then.

Comment: Thanks. Though i figured it out nyself.

Comment: Was it the same solution that I posted?  If so, you should still accept that answer, at least.  If you had a different solution, please post it and self-accept.  Need to make sure that these are "closed out", otherwise they get auto-bumped years from now to see if anyone can answer them.

Comment: The solution was: install code from apt. Set it up. Then uninstall it. Then suddenly it works.

Comment: @PranayChopra Interesting.  Not sure why that worked, but happy it worked for you.  Again, would you post that as a solution and self-accept it?  That will 'close out' the question so it doesn't get auto-bumped later due to lack-of-an-answer.  Thanks!